# os.walk()、shutilcopy()でエラーが発生する

Tags: python

```
#! python3
#デスクトップにある特定のファイルをコピーしてフォルダに移動する

import shutil, os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sugimoto\\Desktop\\atom作業フォルダ')
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.png') or filename.endswith('.py'):
            shutil.copy(filename, '..\\foo')
        else:
            print('該当するファイルが見つかりませんでした。')
```

このコードは.txtファイルと.pngファイルだけをshutil.copy()でコピーするコードです。
しかしこれを実行すると、No such file or directory: 'third-party.txt'（そんなファイルはありません。）というエラーがでてしまいます。

しかしながら

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sugimoto\\Desktop\\atom作業フォルダ')
folder = os.getcwd()
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in  filenames:    
        print('ファイル: ' + filename)
```

↑のコードを実行すると確かに大量のファイルが表示されるのです。ファイルは存在するのに、ファイルが存在しないというエラーがでてしまいます。これは何が原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: os.path.join()で修正後、良好に動作することを確認。しかし該当ファイルがなかった場合、全てに該当するファイルが見つかりませんでした。と表示されるのでelse:文は必要ないことがわかった。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フォルダ階層の途中がコピー元のファイル名として欠けているのでしょう。`shutil.copy` の呼び出しは次のようになるでしょう。

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(foldername, filename), '..\\foo')
```

Comment: プログラム修正後、正常に動作することを確認しました。os.path.join()の使い方を深く知れた気がします。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。